# Stop Word MailMerge Before It Starts

Tags: vba, ms-word, mailmerge

I created a Word (2022) mailmerge document. Later I changed the .docx to a .docm so I could do some post-mailmerge processing on the generated output. I added VBA code to Document_Open() to programatically determine the Excel source data folder and file. However, when opening the Word file, it always prompts for the source data location. The minor issue is that I have to tell the users to always answer "Opening this document will run the following SQL command" with "No". The major issue is that the source folder with which I created the Word doc likely won't exist on the users' computers. Is there a way to prevent the mailmerge start so I can set everything up in the Document_Open routine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found another post that gave a solution. I opened the mailmerge document and answered the "Opening this document..." message with "No", which disconnects the data source from the document. I then saved the document, and the next time I opened it I was no longer prompted.

Comment: Welcome to SO!  As this answered your own question, you should accept it as an answer; This will help others when searching for similar questions to pick up yours, because searchers always try to look for questions that already have answers.